# iOS 10+ notifications

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I added remote notifications to my app but I still have an issue that I can't get around.

If the app is in foreground and the user taps an action button, the body's code will be executed as well which is undesired in my app. I want to have separate code for tapping the body and tapping an action button. If you're wondering where the body's code is at, it's in the `didReceive response` AppDelegate function.

If you need me to post any code, let me know.

Comment: [Action Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html) You will want to read the "Adding Custom Actions to Your Categories" section to get started.

Comment: @JacobBoyd I already did. I already have actions that are working. For some actions, I need them to open the app and execute some code.

Comment: @tarek can you clarify what you mean by body's code? Do you mean that you have some code in the `userNotificationCenter`'s `willPresent` method (which is called when app is active) and some code in the `didReceive` method (called when app is inactive), and it's calling the code in `didReceive`?